# PHPFox: Insert the cover image into ALL website pages

Tags: phpfox

I need a bit help about as follow:

Into the "profile" page is present the cover image. This is visible only into the "profile" page. What I'm trying to do is to insert the cover image into ALL other pages too (home, friends, members, ext...). Into "template.html.php" file I found the reference to the module, that is:  {module name='profile.logo'}

By following the path, I also found the two files:  "logo.html.php"  and  "logo.class.php".
I've been able to edit the cover's position and size too, but any way after many attemps I haven't been able to make the cover visible on ALL other pages.

Can someone of you guys help me please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How about making a block and placing it in position 9 or 7? 
Another way might be editing template.html.php and removing the conditional to always display profile.logo regardless of controller

Ps im at my phone its 1:40am and i cant see the code right now

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...
Can you tell me how removing the conditional profile.logo to always display regardless of the controller?
Thank you very much!